# Android - how to create file object from Imageview image

Tags: android, kotlin, post, imageview

Im making and android app which let the user select an image from the phone and load it to an ImageView. The further process is to send the image as a POST request to a PHP script

It all works fine if I load the image to a File object from the file location, but this require that the user open a setting on the phone which allow the app to access and manage local files..

So, is there a way to read the image from the imagview into a File object?
This is my current working code

```
    val fil = File(getRealPathFromURI(imageUri!!).toString())
    
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 30){
                    if (!Environment.isExternalStorageManager()){
                        var getpermission =  Intent()
                        getpermission.setAction(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
                        startActivity(getpermission);
                    }
                }
    
    
                var reqB = RequestBody.create("image/*".toMediaTypeOrNull(),fil)
               
                var part = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file",fil.name,reqB)
```

Comment: `but this require that the user open a setting on the phone which allow the app to access and manage local files.` Well strange. Why would that be so? Before you said: `let the user select an image from the phone and load it to an ImageView.`. What would be the difference ? Selecting a file would be the same.

Comment: `So, is there a way to read the image from the imagview into a File object?` Ehy would you get it from an imageview if you loaded the view from a selected file? Just remember which file.

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin throws an access error if I try to load it to a File object if the users dont allow it through the settings on the phone. I believe its a security issue on android.

Really what I want to do is

1. Let the user select an existing image on the phone
2. Display it in an imageview
3. Create a function which get the selected image into an MultipartBody.part without the user having to grant the app access to special rights